# Google Sheets query column=column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am not familiar with google sheets, but I have been sent an assignment and I don't want to take the time to convert the whole thing over to an actual database. Is a way to take one column of values (A) and another (B) and check if there is any value in A that is equal to any value in B via queries. I tried

```
=query(*table*, "SELECT *name of row* WHEN A=B", 1)
```

but that just seems to check each row.

**For you visual types, I have a database**

```
  | A | B |
--+---+---+ 
1 | 1 | 0 |
--+---+---+ 
2 | 1 | 2 |
--+---+---+
3 | 1 | 1 |
--+---+---+
4 | 2 | 3 |
```

I want to select rows 2 and 3.
*I didn't see a duplicate. Doesn't help how Google doesn't really document this stuff very well.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how you use query:

**`=QUERY(A1:B; "select B where A = '1'"; 0)`**

- **`A1:B`** - the range you want to import
- **`select B`** - select all columns of given range
- **`where A = '1'`** - where in column **A** are cells with content **`1`**
- **`1`** - stands for 1 heading row (**`0`** for no rows, **`2`** for two rows, etc.)

---

but maybe you seek this:

**`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A=B1:B; "match"; ))`**

and query version would be:

**`=QUERY(A1:B; "select A where A=B"; 0)`**

Comment: I went ahead and converted it to a SQL database (because I know that better), but this did help me and it does work in google sheets, thanks.